# Ignoring Field in Apache Olingo

Tags: java, apache, odata, olingo

Currently my Project is using the JPA for the Database Connection.

I'm also using the default OdataJPA Processor.

How can i achieve **not** to include certain fields for example ("password") in my odata2 API response. Or do I really have to implement a customOdataJPAProcessor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way for excluding some JPA entity attributes is to define a JPA-EDM mapping model. This is basically an XML file which adheres to [this schema](http://olingo.apache.org/resources/RedefiningTheMetadataSchema). You can read more about it in the documentation here: [redefining OData JPA metadata](https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata2/tutorials/jparedefinemetadata.html).

You have two different ways of linking the mapping model XML, either you specify a file name of a file located in the WEB-INF folder (assuming that you are building a WAR) or, if this is not flexible enough, you can create a [JPA EDM extension](https://olingo.apache.org/javadoc/odata2/org/apache/olingo/odata2/jpa/processor/api/model/JPAEdmExtension.html) and [return the mapping model file as a stream](https://olingo.apache.org/javadoc/odata2/org/apache/olingo/odata2/jpa/processor/api/model/JPAEdmExtension.html#getJPAEdmMappingModelStream--).

This is how such a file may look like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<JPAEDMMappingModel xmlns="http://www.apache.org/olingo/odata2/jpa/processor/api/model/mapping">
    <PersistenceUnit name="My_Persistence_Unit">
        <JPAEntityTypes>
            <JPAEntityType name="MyEntity">
                <EDMEntityType>MyEntity</EDMEntityType>
                <EDMEntitySet>MyEntities</EDMEntitySet>
                <JPAAttributes>
                    <JPAAttribute name="attribute" exclude="true" />
                </JPAAttributes>
                <JPARelationships />
            </JPAEntityType>
        </JPAEntityTypes>
        <JPAEmbeddableTypes />
    </PersistenceUnit>
</JPAEDMMappingModel>
```